# MySQL Unknown column in field list.. occurs with uppercase columns only

Tags: mysql, sql

This works:

```
INSERT INTO people (`name`, `job`) values ('Bob', 'sales')
```

but this fails:

```
INSERT INTO people (`name`, `Sold`) values ('Bob', '56')
```

Giving the error:
`Unknown column 'Sold' in 'field list'`

All fields are of type varchar. Can't figure this out!

Comment: Is that error message right? Should it not mention `'Sold'`?

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes that was a typo. Edited original post.

Comment: @Michael: No. Column names are not case sensitive.

Comment: @Michael I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @ypercube Indeed I just checked the docs. Mixed up with table names.

Comment: @muistooshort: Are you sure? I thought it didn't matter.

Comment: @norse: Does table `people` have a column named `Sold` ?

Comment: @Norse can you post your CREATE TABLE code in case you made a typo there too?

Comment: @ypercube: Looks like I'm wrong and this is another non-standard MySQLism. *Insert miscellaneous MySQL hate and ranting here*

Comment: I've found the problem after looking at my `CREATE TABLE` code. Thanks Ozzy. Can a mod close this?

Comment: @Norse: You can flag it for closing yourself. (or delete it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is referring to the table column name `Sold` in the table `people`.

Your two examples are meaningless because you didn't successfully insert a value into the column `Sold` in the first example. Neither did you successfully insert a number into a VARCHAR column in the first example.

This has nothing to do with a type mismatch, the error says this column is unknown (doesn't exist).

Comment: "Your two examples are meaningless because you didn't successfully insert a value into the column Sold" Yeah that's the problem I'm having!

Comment: @Norse To clarify what I said: in the first example, you inserted values into the columns `name` and `job` NOT `Sold` so the example `this works but this doesn't` is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO people (name, sold) values ('Bob', '56')
```

I'll need more informations about table

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO test (`name`, `Sold`) values ('Bob', '56')
```

worked for me given that the table was created like this..

```
create table test (id int, name varchar(6),Sold varchar(4),job varchar(7));
```

please check your data type in the created 'Sold' column.

it could be a boolean in your case..